# I am trying to export my npm package. How to do it properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-publish

I've created an npm package

```
class Person {
     constructor() {}
     sayHello() {console.log("Hello World!")}
}

module.exports = Person;
```

After doing `npm i my-package` it was added the lib to my project.

On my index.js I am doing the following:

```
const Person = require('my-package');

const david = new Person();
```

But I get this error:
`Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/test/node_modules/my-package/app.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

It works fine when I require it like this:

```
const Person = require('./node_modules/my-package/person.js');

const david = new Person();
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I set my package to export Person using `const Person = require('my-package');`

Comment: `module.exports.my-package` is invalid. Consider using `module.exports = Person`? --- Also please share the `package.json`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you. It indeed was a package,json issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main in my `package.json` file pointed to app.js (default by npm).

I had to change it to point to my actual main.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...

  "main": "index.js", // <------ I changed it from app.js to my actual main
   
   ...
}
```

Thank you @evolutionxbox for your comment. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to import it like `const Person = require("my-package")` you would want to export the Person class by default:

```
module.exports = Person;
```

Also make sure your `main` property in the package.json is set to whatever root file you want.